# Does Alexa have an API where I can get "Rank", "Subdomain" and "Percent of Visitors"? (Python)

Tags: python, web, rank, alexa-skills-kit

Does Alexa have an API where I can get "Rank", "Subdomain" and "Percent of Visitors"? I keep getting redirected to 'Amazon Web Services,' but I have no intent in using any storage or voice recognition services. Where do I do find the Alexa service where I can get data on web rankings?

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you are looking for the Alexa Web Info Service (AWIS), not the voice recognition ecosystem that powers Amazon's Echo; developer documentation on AWIS can be found here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AlexaWebInfoService/latest/

And here is the Amazon Webservices page with pricing / amount of free requests / further links:

https://aws.amazon.com/en/awis/